# Qiskit problem with visualization in libray not functioning

Tags: qiskit

This is IBM quantum simulator with the help of Python and qiskit code. But i am stuck[[image]][image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBwR5.png)

I just want to know why this is not working.

There is a youtube video on it but still need help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because there is no real description of what the problem is, distilled down to a minimally reproducible problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I see a large screenshot of code and errors without asking a question that somebody here can really answer. Additionally, please describe what you've done so far (e.g. things attempted and researched).

Answer (score -1):

The fundamental issue is a mistake in your source code. In cell 42 you are collecting the result from the simulator execution by calling `.result()` and then not setting the return to the variable `result` that you expect in cell 57. It looks like you have imported the qiskit's result module (something like `from qiskit import result`) above in a cell that's not visible which is getting accessed when you run `result.get_counts()` which is the root cause of you error. To avoid the conflict and fix your issue I would change cell 42 to be something like:

```py
exec_result = execute(circuit, backend=simulator).result()
```

and then change cell 57 to be:

```py
counts = exec_result.get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

This should fix the specific error your seeing in this case.